# PHP - printf with json arguments

Tags: php, arrays, json, printf, encode

I tried to pass as arguments in printf encoded json array. However, due to the nature of the json array it creates an error with printf: `printf(): Too few arguments`

Is there a way to pass encoded json array in `printf` method like this:

```
$val   = 10;
$min   = 0;
$max   = 100;
$steps = array( 1, 0.1, 0.01 );
$units = array( 'px', 'em', '%' );

printf(
    '<input type="range" value="%d" min="%d" max="%d" step="0.01" data-steps="%s" data-units="%s">',
    floatval( $val ),
    floatval( $min ),
    floatval( $max ),
    json_encode( $steps ),
    json_encode( $units )
);
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide insight into your data and php environment? I don't get an error with some test data.

Comment: Works for me https://3v4l.org/TOaXa (though the HTML will be invalid)

Comment: Lets just hope the array is sequentialy indexed integer/floats :)

Comment: Could you show the contents of your variables? Do they have `%`'s in them?

Comment: In fact it does not work if you chain several json in the arguments of printf. I will update my example.

Comment: @freaky Your edited example still works fine: https://3v4l.org/Vi3ag (Although, as others have pointed out, the resulting HTML is invalid because you haven't escaped the data). Please include an example that you've actually tested and doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, effectively it's working. I made a mistake with a non escaped % percent string in my code in fact. It's not due to the json... But thank you it help me to identify the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine but it generates this piece of HTML

```
<input type="range" value="10" min="0" max="100" step="0.01"
       data-steps="[1,0.1,0.01]" data-units="["px","em","%"]">
```

which is invalid because of the double quotes included in the JSON content.

Any dynamic content you use to generate HTML must be properly HTML-encoded. Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to encode the values returned by [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) before passing them to [`printf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) to generate valid HTML:

```
$val   = 10;
$min   = 0;
$max   = 100;
$steps = array( 1, 0.1, 0.01 );
$units = array( 'px', 'em', '%' );

printf(
    '<input type="range" value="%d" min="%d" max="%d" step="0.01" data-steps="%s" data-units="%s">',
    floatval( $val ),
    floatval( $min ),
    floatval( $max ),
    htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $steps ) ),
    htmlspecialchars( json_encode( $units ) )
);
```

The values returned by [`floatval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) do not need this treatment because they do not contain HTML special characters.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I accept your answer, but finally my issue was no due to this in fact.